# How to handle download pop-up in firefox, while downloading excel using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to download an Excel file from Firefox and Webdriver, but i can't handle the download pop-up.

When click on button i need the file to download automatically, without showing pop-up.

Here is my code:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", Constant.Downloaded_Path);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv/xls/xlsx");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
    "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);
return firefoxProfile;
```

But, the above code is not working. Can any one help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to get the mime type corresponding to the file:

- Open Developer Tools and then the Network tab
- Go back to the page and click on the file to download
- Go back to the network panel and select the first request
- Copy the mime type on the right of Content-Type from the response header:

[image]

- Set the preference "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" with your mime type
- Make sure the download folder "browser.download.dir" exists

Here is a working example with Firefox:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Windows\\temp");
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);  // disable the built-in PDF viewer

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.get("http://www.exinfm.com/free_spreadsheets.html");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Capital Budgeting Analysis")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks Florent. It's working fine for Excel but it's not working for Pdf. Can you help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can add multiple mime type in "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk". The separator is a comma.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work when I set "pdfjs.disabled" flag. It's missing in many other answers/blog posts around.

Comment: This worked like a charm. The key is to get the exact Mime Type the way you explained.

Comment: super useful comment

Answer (score 2):

```
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            // profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", " text/plain, application/octet-stream doc xls pdf txt");
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/csv, text/csv, text/plain,application/octet-stream doc xls pdf txt");
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
            profile.SetPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
            profile.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
            _driverInstance = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

These settings worked for me. Hope it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide mimetypes for the application you want to download.
For python, if you want to enable it for all applications then use the following code

```
import mimetypes
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", ','.join(list(it for it in mimetypes.types_map.values())))
```