# How to handle pop up window dialog to download file automatically with firefox profile in python selenium on Linux (Ubuntu) system

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to download the file automatically from system file download dialog by setting preference in firefox  profile in my python selenium code , but my code is not working.

Browser : Firefox 72.0
Selenium Version : 3.14
OS : linux Ubuntu
Filetype to download: *.enc (encrypted file type)
Path of firefox in linux : /usr/bin/firefox

Code :

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/home/user/Downloads/tests")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-uuencoded,application/octet-stream")
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

[image: Windows download dialog]

Comment: Can someone suggest if we have to set any different preference for *.enc file . Also in firefox profile setting even if I have set ("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False) still the dialog box is visible when the test clicks on download link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct MIME type for `.enc`  is `"text/x-uuencoded"`
Updated as below in code and it's working :

```
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/x-uuencoded")
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Sum i have resolving, my problem was a different Content-Type.

Use this example to resolve your problem , and to understand your Content-Type: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36356422/12911814

In my case the Content-Type was "application/force-download" not "application/pdf"

```
    profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "<path>")
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf, application/force-download")
```

These settings worked for me. Hope it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Firefox 72.0, but with pdf files. This is the code:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/path")
fp.set_preference("browser.download.downloadDir", "/path")
fp.set_preference("browser.download.defaultFolder", "/path")
fp.set_preference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/x-pdf, application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf, application/vnd.cups-pdf")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-pdf, application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf, application/vnd.cups-pdf")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/x-pdf, application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf, application/vnd.cups-pdf")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

I have tried all possible preferences, but it always triggers the download alert.

Comment: Hi @SantinoMagno, and welcome! Given this doesn't look like an answer, may I suggest you turn it into a comment to the main question? This way it'd be clearer it doesn't try to address the original issue. Alternatively, if it's different enough, consider posting your own question!

Comment: Thanks jir, sorry but i haven't reputation to comment the main question...

Comment: No worries - I didn't know you were required to have some rep to be able to do that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work like charm ......

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    import time
    import pyautogui

    try :



        driver = webdriver.Firefox()

        driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        driver.maximize_window()

        driver.get("https://www.citysdk.eu/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/DELIVERABLE_WP4_TA_SRS_0.21.pdf")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
        # Click the OK button and close

        time.sleep(5)
        webelem = driver.find_element_by_id('download')
        webelem.click()

        time.sleep(5)
        print('press enter')
        pyautogui.press('enter')


    except Exception as err:
        print('ERROR: %sn' % str(err))

        driver.quit()
```